# use regular expression in php

Tags: php, html, preg-replace

```
..(content).............
<A HREF="http://test.com/content" >test link </A>
...(continue content)...
```

I want to delete link with content. And also text between link.

Comment: The question is not sufficiently clear.

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't use regex here at all - rather [DOMDocument::loadHTML](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php), then [DOMDocument::getElementsByTagName](http://DOMDocument::getElementsByTagName) and [DOMNode::removeChild](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domnode.removechild.php); finally [DOMDocument::saveHTML](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savehtml.php)

Answer (score 0):

While regular expressions can be used to do this, they will be prone to problems. A more robust solution is using the [DOM extension](http://se.php.net/DOM) or another HTML parser to remove the `a` element in question. Or all `a` elements, for that matter. If you really want to do this with a regular expression, the following should work:

```
preg_replace('/<A (.*?)>(.*?)</A>/i', '', $data);
```

Comment: As you note, this regex will be problematic and will break (e.g. on `<ADDR>`, or even `<A HREF="">...</a>`)

Comment: Fixed the regex, it won't break as easily now. While it is a suboptimal solution (which I point out in the answer), it gets the job done, so I don't really see the need for a downvote.